# Matlab execute UNIX command not working in newer versions

Tags: matlab, unix

I have a script that uses this line of code:

```
system(['cat ' inputfile ' | tr -d ''\000'' | tr -d ''\015'' >& tempfile.txt']);
```

to go through a text file and delete some special characters and then put it into a temp file.

This line of code works in Matlab2012 but not in 2017 as it leads to this error:

```
tr: Illegal byte sequence
cat: stdout: Broken pipe
```

Does anyone know how to get around this issue? Thank you!

Comment: I’m not sure, but you might need to escape the backslash.  MATLAB now recognizes octal constants, this could be the reason your code no longer works. I recommend that you remove the `system` call and just print out the composed string you pass to it. This will give you a hint as to what is wrong.

Comment: I got no error, using 2017b on ubuntu 16.04. I tried inputfile = which('ls.m'); and the tempfile.txt was created with no error.

Comment: Maybe `inputfile` contains spaces? Consider enclosing it in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoded format may not be supported by tr, try changing the locale (refer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141420/tr-complains-of-illegal-byte-sequence):

```
system(['cat ' inputfile  ' | LC_ALL="C" tr -d ''\000''''\015'' >& tempfile.txt']);
```